# What is meant by "object." that prefixes method names in the Python docs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been intensively consulting the Python docs lately, and I can't figure out what the `object.` prefix means. For example, I've been reading about:

```
 __getitem__()
```

and in the docs its definition header is written as:

```
 object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Here's the link to [its entry](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

What added to the confusion is that running:

```
object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

raises the error:

```
type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__()'
```

**Update,,**

I also considered the possibility that it's there to denote instance of a class, but then the **self** parameter becomes invalid.. .

Comment: You're mixing up 3 methods here, `__getitem__`, `__getattr__`, and `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the data model docs. In those docs, `object.` is basically a placeholder. It doesn't refer to the `object` class. `object` doesn't have most of the methods in those docs.

If there was a meaningful class name they could have used, they would have done so, but these docs aren't specific to any particular class. The docs are saying, *if* a class has this method, this is what the Python language internals will assume it means.

Comment: ".., but these docs aren't specific to any particular class". And I guess that since every class in Python is actually object by means of inheritance, then that "object" becomes like a universal placeholder. Although I'm not sure, but this could be simply it.. , thanks, user2357112 supports Monica

Answer (score 1):

`object` is only base class for all Python objects. Every class what you create will be subclass of it. You can't call its attributes itself. Referring to @Brian's comment you can read about it in built-in help.

Answer (score 0):

`object` is the base class of all Python types.

As for the error you got, the documentation for [Special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) does not describe pre-defined methods. Instead, it describes callbacks that you can define on your own classes. Also, `__getattribute__` is not the same as `__getattr__`. When I type `dir(object)` in the Python REPL, I see it has a `__getattribute__` attribute, but no `__getattr__`.

I'm not sure why that documentation prefixes the method names with `object.`. I guess the `object` there is supposed to be *any* object, not just the class.